# Add existing make environment to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cmd, makefile, environment-variables

I have a question about eclipse and make. I have created a make environment which acts as follow:

I have a batch file (Start.bat) which SET´s variables for further usage (e.g. `SET TOOL_PATH = blabla`).

After calling this I use my make.bat `<option>`, which calls the `make.ext -f Makefile.mak <option>` with the given option e.g. make.bat all -sj4. The environment variables which are set in Start.bat are very important for the running of the overall make environment.

This works very fine and now I would like to import this in eclipse but I am not familiar with eclipse. I need from eclipse that when I would like to run a make, first the Start.bat is called and then the make.bat `<option>` is called.

What I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can import your project as 'existing make file project'

In the project settings you should be able to define pre-biuld steps and call the batch there or define a specific target (e.g. start) that calls the start batch and is executed before your 'make'.

I dont know exactly at the moment how to do this the best way, but I think you are fast into it.